# css input radio checked не работает

Tags: css, input, label, radio

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает input checked?

```css
.add-rating {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotateY(180deg);
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.add-rating ul {
   display: flex;
}
.add-rating label {
   font-size: 0px;
}
.add-rating li input{
   display: none;
}
.add-rating li label:before {
    content: '\f006';
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.add-rating li label:after {
    content: '\f005';
    font-family: fontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffc107;
    top: 22px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s;
}
    /*работает*/
.add-rating li label:hover:after,
    /*не работает*/
    .add-rating li label:hover ~ li label:after,
    .add-rating li input:checked ~ li label:after {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-rating">  
    <tr>
        <th><label for="id_star_speed_0">Star speed:</label></th>
        <td>
            <ul id="id_star_speed">
                <li><label for="id_star_speed_0"><input type="radio" name="star_speed" value="5" required id="id_star_speed_0">100</label></li>
                <li><label for="id_star_speed_1"><input type="radio" name="star_speed" value="4" required id="id_star_speed_1">80</label></li>
                <li><label for="id_star_speed_2"><input type="radio" name="star_speed" value="3" required id="id_star_speed_2">60</label></li>
                <li><label for="id_star_speed_3"><input type="radio" name="star_speed" value="2" required id="id_star_speed_3">40</label></li>
                <li><label for="id_star_speed_4"><input type="radio" name="star_speed" value="1" required id="id_star_speed_4">20</label></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш селектор берёт следующего ближайшего соседа label для input, которого нету

Comment: А как нужно? Уже все варианты перепробовал.

Comment: Размещать label до или после input, а не input в label

Comment: А если нет возможности переписать html?

Comment: Как это нету возможности?

Comment: Это зашито где-то в django